# How it comes that ldapsearch output can't be piped

Tags: pipe, stdout, ldap, openldap, sasl

ldapsearch always outputs an authentication message with every query at the beginning:

```
SASL/GSS-SPNEGO authentication started
SASL username: user.principal@DOMAIN.NAME
SASL SSF: 56
SASL data security layer installed.
...
<regular output>
```

if I do `ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -b cn=<omitted>,cn=groups,dc=lan,dc=<ommited>,dc=de "(cn=<omitted>.nextcloud.users)"|grep -v SASL` it doesn't disappear.

If append `2> /dev/null` it doesn't help either.

This is annoying I am looking for some way to not show this SASL output when I do ldapsearch queries. The ldapsearch command ist executed against a samba4-LDAP

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Q` to disable SASL-related messages.

```
ldapsearch -Q cn=whatever
```

To redirect stderr you need to add `2>/dev/null` *next to the command* which produces stderr output – that is, the redirection must be near ldapsearch, before the `| grep ...` part.

```
ldapsearch cn=whatever 2>/dev/null | grep foo
```